# How to reference a figure placed in the appendix

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, appendices, ieeetran

In my `IEEEtran` document, I had to create `\appendix` section at the end of my documents and place some figures there. When I try to reference these figures from any section using `\ref{X}`, I get **??** which means any thing in the appendix is not recognized! How do I solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided a Minimum Working Example (MWE). I will try to help you with the following example code:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{A Heuristic Coconut-based Algorithm}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell}
\IEEEauthorblockA{School of Electrical and\\
Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology\\
Atlanta, Georgia 30332--0250\\
Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Homer Simpson}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Twentieth Century Fox\\
Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{James Kirk\\
and Montgomery Scott}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Starfleet Academy\\
San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212\\
Fax: (888) 555--1212}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{One}

See figures~\ref{fig1}, \ref{appfig1}. and~\ref{appfig2}.

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\caption{Caption text.}\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

%\appendix % for single appendix
\appendices  % for more than one appendix section

% By default figure number is continuous on appendix. You can 
% change this by the following two lines
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{section}.\arabic{figure}}

\section{One}

\subsection{One}

\blindtext
\blindtext

\subsection{Two}
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\caption{Caption text.}\label{appfig1}
\end{figure}

\section{Two}

\subsection{One}

\blindtext
\blindtext

\subsection{Two}
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\caption{Caption text.}\label{appfig2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```